# How to pass ajax data value to data-percent in php?

Tags: php

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#source").change(function(){
            source = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"source":source},
                url:"percent.php",
                success:function(data){
                    show = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#total").html(show.total);
                    $("#sources").html(show.sources);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="bar">
    <span class="percent"><div id="total"></div></span>
    <div class="progress" data-percent="">
        <span class="title"><div id="sources"></div></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have create a bar percentage graph. In percent.php page I have calculate percentage through query which work fine but I am unable to pass total value to data-percent. So, How can I pass the total val to data-percent ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `data-percent` ?? Where is that in your code

Comment: @RiggsFolly its on the div with class of progress. Hidden in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign value to data- like this : https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/ZRrZQJ

```
 $(".progress").attr('data-percent', 5);
 $(".progress").data('percent', 5);
```

you can write same code in ajax

Comment: how can I implement in my ajax code I am trying but still no changes @BhumiShah

Comment: have you tried to put this line in your ajax success?